# how to create a user User-Defined Functions do a string concatenation in kusto

Tags: azure, kql

i need create a one using array i create following queries for do that

```
let MyDistinct = (T:(table:dynamic)) {
  range x from 0 to array_length(table) step 1
    T | extend  strcat_array(details[0].parsedStack[x].method,'(',details[0].parsedStack[x].assembly,')')
};
let T1 = MyDistinct((exceptions | extend itemType =iif(itemType=='exception',itemType,"") | where itemType=='exception' and type == "System.Web.HttpException" | where timestamp >= ago(7d) | project callStack=details[0].parsedStack));
union
(T1),
(T2| project outerMessage,type,problemId,outerAssembly,itemType,operation_Name,operation_Id,operation_ParentId,client_Type,client_IP,cloud_RoleInstance,assembly)
```

i need to put details[0].parsedStack[x] values as a string to following format xxx_(xxx) `"System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)"`

what i need to do is

this the values inside - details[0].parsedStack and this come from the database

callStack

```
    [
{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance","level":0,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController","level":1,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit","level":2,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":3,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":4,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":5,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0","level":7,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker.Invoke","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0","level":9,"line":0},

{"assembly":"Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep","level":10,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0","level":11,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker.Invoke","level":12,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl","level":13,"line":0},

{"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep","level":14,"line":0}

]
```

I want to make above Jason array to following format

System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

x.x.x.x.x (x,x,x)

x.x.x.x.x (x,x,x)

```
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0 (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker.Invoke (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0 (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep (Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0 (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication+StepInvoker.Invoke (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

note details[0].parsedStack[0] is a dictionary but way i write i getting errors time to time please give me help make this right

Comment: you may want to clarify how the input looks like, and how the expected output looks like. with the current phrasing of the question, it's not clear (and makes it harder to give you a meaningful reply)

Comment: details are updated..

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance","level":0,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController","level":1,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit","level":2,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":3,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":4,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest","level":5,"line":0}),
    dynamic({"assembly":"System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","method":"System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute","level":6,"line":0})
]
| project result = strcat(d.method, "(", d.assembly, ")")
```

Comment: the `datatable` operator is just a means to provide an input dataset, without having access to your databas/data. assuming you have a column (or dynamic property) whose value is similar to that in the column `d` in the example, you can apply the logic in the example over it